# Proxy Api error on Ext JS 4

Tags: javascript, extjs

I'm just started playing Ext JS 4 and following to create MVC application using Ext JS 4. The article URL at http://www.sencha.com/learn/the-mvc-application-architecture/. But when i'm running the application on Chrome it's showed error. Chrome says: "You are using a ServerProxy but have not supplied it with a url.", but the application run well on Firefox and Safari. Can anyone tell me how to fixed the bug?

```
Ext.define('AM.store.Users', {
   extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
   model: 'AM.model.User',
   autoLoad: true,
   autoSync: true,
   proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        api: {
            read: 'data/users.json',
            update: 'data/updateUsers.json'
        },
        //url: 'data/users.json',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'users',
            successProperty: 'success'
        }
    }
});
```

Thanks.

@andriansandi

Comment: Although you are following the tutorial, but please post your code

Comment: pls look my code on store/Users.js

Comment: Can you try to register the proxy on the Model, instead of the store?

Comment: So the correct is proxy on Model not on Store?

Answer (score 0):

Are you running this from a web server or just as a file?  If you're loading your html from a file your problem might be caused by a security exception.

If it's happening when you make a new model try adding the create url to your config like so:

```
api: {
        read: 'data/users.json',
        update: 'data/updateUsers.json',
        create: 'data/updateUsers.json'
     }
```

Comment: I'm running from a web server

Answer (score 0):

Ran into same problem however adding create: 'data/updateUsers.json' is solving the issue, am not sure if its right